# MYSQL retrieving a field value based on another

Tags: php, mysqli

MYSQL I would like to retrieve a value of a field in columnX where a field value for columnY is specified. There maybe more than one row where this occurs but the first one will do. it would be excellent if you could provide the php. Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this SQL:

```
SELECT `columnX` FROM `table` WHERE `columnY` = $value LIMIT 1
```

In PHP:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT `columnX` FROM `table` WHERE `columnY` = $value LIMIT 1");
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['columnX'];
```

Comment: Thanks again. The reason that I don't know is that I'm a front end developer and haven't done any SQL before however I've been personalising some examples. I'm also not too familiar with this site but learning the ropes now. I have accepted the answers! Sorry for the delay in reply I have been on holiday.

Comment: No problem, everybody has to start somewhere. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to do it in sql you can use the IF condition like :

```
SELECT IF(X=0,Y,1) As cond FROM table
```

In PHP:

```
$query = $mysqli->query('SELECT IF(X=0,Y,1) As cond FROM table');
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['cond'];
```

thanks to "Daniel Li"